# How to prove that the flat torus is indeed flat?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, curvature

The $n$-dimensional torus can be obtained as a quotient: $T^n=\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$.

As pointed out [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/450130/104576), the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is invariant under translation by the elements of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ so it descends to the quotient (i.e there is a unique Riemannian metric on $T^n$ making the canonical projection a Riemannian isometry).

Is there an easy way to see that the curvature (of that metric on $T^n$)  is zero? 
I am aware of [O'Neill's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_submersion#Properties), but I would like to find a more elementary way to prove this without using it. Is it possible? (at least for $n=2$ )?

Comment: That looks like an $n$-dimensional torus :-)

Comment: Curvature is a local invariant, $\Bbb R^n$ is flat, and the projection $\Bbb R^n \to T^n$ is (by construction of the metric you chose on $T^n$) a local isometry. Is that satisfying?

Comment: Isn't it locally isometric to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @MikeMiller: great minds think alike :-)

Comment: @MikeMiller: You are right of course. The important point is that $Z^n$ is discrete, so the fact that the projection is a submersion automatically implies its an immersion, and immersions are locally embeddings. This is what I was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sake of completeness I am writing the full answer, as suggested by Mike Miller:

$Z^n$ is discrete implies dim($\mathbb{T}^n$)=dim($\mathbb{R}^n$), so the fact that the projection is a submersion automatically implies its an immersion, and immersions are locally embeddings.

It is a local isometry (not just an embedding) by the construction of the metric.