# When does a space admit a flat metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

Once upon a time I was told that the torus is flat. This was supposed to be surprising, since the ordinary picture of a torus we have in our heads looks inherently curved. However, thinking instead of a torus as a square in the plane with opposite points identified, it becomes 'clear' that the torus at least *admits* a flat metric, because the plane admits a flat metric.

However, a two-holed torus can also be obtained in this way: it is an octagon in the plane with appropriate pairs of edges identified. However, by the Gauss-Bonnet theorem, this surface does not admit a flat metric.

Thus, something about the way we make the identifications for the 1-torus is compatible with the flat metric structure on the plane, and this is not so for the 2-torus. I am hence lead to ask:

**Given a smooth manifold $M$ obtained from $\mathbb{R}^n$ by appropriate identifications, is there some general criterion for determining whether the flat metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ descends to $M$? Or is the $n$-dimensional torus  particularly special in its ability to inherit a metric from the plane? If so, what is special about it?**

Comment: Metric tensors pullback. So if you have a manifold as a quotient, there is a map $X\to X/\sim$. Given a metric on the quotient, you may always pull it back to the starting space without further assumptions. Pushing the metric down from the parent space requires more work, which I guess is the point of the question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let $M$ be a manifold and $G$ a discrete group acting freely and proper discontinuously, then $M/G$ is a manifold. If $g$ is a Riemannian metric on $M$, then it descends to a Riemannian metric on $M/G$ if and only if the group $G$ acts by isometries; to be precise, by 'descends to a Riemannian metric on $M/G$', I mean there is a Riemannian metric $g'$ on $M/G$ such that $g = \pi^*g'$ where $\pi : M \to M/G$ is the quotient map. To see how to construct $g'$ from $g$, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/450130/39599) where I show that the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ descends to the torus $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$; here the group $G = \mathbb{Z}^n$ is acting by translations which are isometries of the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

If $(M, g)$ is flat, and $g$ is complete, then its universal cover is isometric to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with its standard metric, so every complete flat manifold is a quotient of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with its standard metric by a discrete group of isometries which acts freely; note, every discrete group of isometries of $\mathbb{R}^n$ acts properly discontinuously. If in addition $M$ is compact, then the group action is cocompact; a discrete group of isometries which acts cocompactly is called a [crystallographic group](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Crystallographic_group), if it also acts freely, it is called a Bieberbach group; note, a Bieberbach group can equivalently be defined as a torsion-free crystallographic group (this is the usual definition).  Bieberbach showed that an $n$-dimensional crystallographic group has a finite index subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$, from which it follows that every compact flat manifold is finitely covered by a torus.

Note that not every subgroup of isometries of $\mathbb{R}^n$ gives rise to a flat manifold as it may not act freely on $\mathbb{R}^n$. For example, every isometry of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a composition of reflections, rotations, and translations; the first two transformations have fixed points, so they don't act freely on $\mathbb{R}^2$. If the subgroup does not act freely, the quotient will be a flat orbifold instead of a flat manifold. Moreover, every flat orbifold arises this way, see Theorem $13.3.10$ of *Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds* (second edition) by Ratcliffe. In particular, a quotient of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by a crystallographic group which is not a Bieberbach group gives a compact flat orbifold which is not an manifold.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you. Could you comment about how this generalises to the orbifold case? It appears that there is a 1-to-1 correspondence between crystallographic groups and (2D flat) orbifolds: is this to say that some of the 17 wallpaper groups don't act freely on the plane?

Comment: @gj255: I don't know much about orbifolds. I will try to look into it and update my answer later.

Comment: Yes, most of the 17 wallpaper groups do not act freely on the plane. In fact, the only ones which do act freely on the plane are the actions of $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ whose quotient is a torus, and the actions of the non-abelian semi direct product $\mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}$ whose quotient is the Klein bottle. Every other wallpaper group has torsion elements, each of which is either a rotation (which fixes a point) or a reflection (which fixes a line).

Comment: I believe it's also true that every compact Euclidean orbifold is covered by the plane and hence is a quotient of a crystallographic group.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thanks for expanding your answer. One final question: what is your working definition of a Bieberbach group and how does it differ from a crystallographic group?

Comment: @gj255: A discrete, torsion-free group of isometries of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which has a compact fundamental domain. A crystallographic group need not be torsion-free.

Answer (score 28):

The [octagon with edges identified](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1239104/) appears to be different because you cannot ***tile*** the entire flat (Euclidean) plane with octagons in such a way that everything is OK when you cross the "border" and move to the adjacent octagon.

Instead, you can tile the *hyperbolic plane* with octagons in the correct way. So the genus-2 surface can inherit the negative-curvature metric of the hyperbolic plane. Pictures: [Wikipedia: Order-8 octagonal tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-8_octagonal_tiling)

Answer (score 13):

You can use this idea to put a flat metric (in a sense) on any surface obtained by identifying the edges of a polygon in pairs. But the metric won't be *smooth* unless whenever you have a set of vertices being identified, the angles at those vertices add up to exactly $360^\circ$. It works for the square because you have four $90^\circ$ angles meeting at a point. To see what goes wrong, cut a regular octagon out of a piece of paper, then tear off eight pieces containing the eight vertices and try to tape them all together so that all the vertices meet at a point. You can do it, but you'll get a shape that can't be flattened out without a lot of creasing.

Here's an example of a hexagon that works:

[image]

The vertices labeled A are all identified with each other, as are the vertices labeled B. Since the angles all measure $120^\circ$, each set of three angles fits together to make a smooth flat surface. (The resulting surface is homeomorphic to the torus, as it must be because it has a flat metric. It's an interesting exercise to prove this directly by cutting and pasting.)

The reason you can put a smooth hyperbolic metric on a surface of genus $n=2$ or more is that as long as $n\ge 2$, it's possible to find a regular $4n$-sided geodesic polygon in the hyperbolic plane whose angles are all exactly $360^\circ/4n$, so they all fit together to make a smooth surface with a hyperbolic metric.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you sure the hexagon example doesn't tile the plane?

Comment: @gj255: Oops -- yes, of course it does. Forget that statement.

Answer (score 4):

If the manifold is closed, it is finitely covered by the $n$-flat torus.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_manifold